# SQL Update Query from sum and first row of another table

Tags: sql-server

I am creating the SQL query which will update Quantities of 'Table A' from from 'Table B'. However couple of fields in the Table B are not to be sum and their latest value (First or Last row value based on Date Order) is also to be updated in the 'Table A'. Below is the query sofar.

```
UPDATE r
SET r.Completed = t.MoveQty, r.Scrapped = t.ScrapQty, r.ReWork = t.ReworkQty
FROM JobRoutings r
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT JobID, ScanFromProcessID, SUM(ScanMoveQty) MoveQty, Sum(ScanScrapQty) ScrapQty, Sum(ScanRecutQty) ReworkQty
  FROM JobTrans
  GROUP BY  JobID, ScanFromProcessID
) t ON r.JobID = t.JobID AND r.ProcessID  = t.ScanFromProcessID;
```

Fields which are needed to be included in the above query are:

Latest value of [`JobTrans`].ScannedDate and [`JobTrans`].PC [ORDER BY ScannedDate] need to update [`JobRoutings`].LastScanDate and [`JobRoutings`].PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way that joins a 2nd subquery and gets the latest PC/ScannedDate values using ROW_NUMBER():

```
UPDATE r
SET r.Completed = t.MoveQty, r.Scrapped = t.ScrapQty, r.ReWork = t.ReworkQty, r.LastScanDate = t.ScannedDate, r.PC = t.PC
FROM JobRoutings r
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT JobTrans.JobID, JobTrans.ScanFromProcessID, t2.ScannedDate, t2.PC, SUM(ScanMoveQty) MoveQty, Sum(ScanScrapQty) ScrapQty, Sum(ScanRecutQty) ReworkQty
  FROM JobTrans 
  INNER JOIN
  (
      SELECT JobID, ScanFromProcessID, ScannedDate, PC, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobID, ScanFromProcessID ORDER BY ScannedDate DESC) AS rn
      FROM JobTrans
  )t2 ON JobTrans.JobID = t2.JobID AND JobTrans.ScanFromProcessID = t2.ScanFromProcessID AND t2.rn = 1
  GROUP BY  JobTrans.JobID, JobTrans.ScanFromProcessID, t2.ScannedDate, t2.PC
) t ON r.JobID = t.JobID AND r.ProcessID  = t.ScanFromProcessID
```

Comment: Hi, Great work but it is updating a single row among the JobId in the JobRoutings. The ScanDate and PC should be included with each row of JobTrans and then Update the JobRouting. You got it very close. I think the 2nd inner join should be inside the first inner join.

Comment: @Khalil Great! Can you mark as the correct answer? Thank you :)